# PyFlink window aggregation not triggering

Tags: python, flink-streaming, data-stream, pyflink

I have a problem that my window aggregation accumulates all results, but do not return it, and my result stream is empty
I suspect it has something to do with windows triggering, but cannot figure out how

```
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)


class MyTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssigner):

    def extract_timestamp(self, element, previous_element_timestamp):
        date_str = element[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        # print(element,datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp())
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()


joined_data_stream = joined_data_stream.assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(
    WatermarkStrategy
    .for_bounded_out_of_orderness(Duration.of_days(1))
    .with_timestamp_assigner(MyTimestampAssigner())
)


keyed_stream = joined_data_stream.key_by(lambda x: x[1])


class AverageAggregate(functions.AggregateFunction):

    def create_accumulator(self) -> [int, int]:
        return 0, 0
    def add(self, value, accumulator):
        print('ADDING')
        return accumulator[0]+value[3] , accumulator[1] + 1
    def merge(self, a: [int, int], b: [int, int]) -> [int, int]:
        print('MERGING')
        return a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]
    def get_result(self, accumulator):
        print('GETTING',accumulator[0] / accumulator[1])
        return accumulator[0] / accumulator[1]


avg_stream = joined_data_stream.key_by(lambda x: x[1]).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(2),Time.days(1))) \
    .aggregate(AverageAggregate(),accumulator_type=Types.TUPLE([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()]),output_type=Types.DOUBLE())
```

Here is all the code I have now, would be grateful for any tip given

**UPDATE**
The problem was my timestamp assignments, replacing this

```
return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
```

With this

```
return int(datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()*1000)
```

Fixed it all

Comment: The window isn't firing because the watermarks aren't advancing. Does the dataset you are using for testing have at least 5 days worth of data? Could you have idle or empty source partitions?

Comment: Yes, it has
I've actually got the answer myself, the thing is my timestamps were somehow broken for java, so had to multiply it by 1000 and round by int, and everything is working.(not quite sure why so)
Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you have found a solution to the problem,
in case you still don't know why it works it's because when you call the `.timestamp()` it returns the timestamp in seconds
e.g.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
1704060000.0
```

while flink expects ms that's why it works well after multiplying by 1000